STM32G0 locks up on POR
I've used the STM32L series for many years but recently used the STM32G030F6 in a new design and have noted several times (on multiple devices) that the uC enters a locked up state on power up and is unresponsive until it is power cycled.  Importantly, a hard reset does not clear the condition.
The uC is running from its internal RC oscillators (i.e. it's not an xtal startup issue) and there is only a 100nF cap to ground on nReset. Bulk capacitance is 2.2uF + 0.1uF (MLCC) located close to the Vdd, Vss pins. SWDIO and SWCLK are floating.
It only seems to happen after the device has been off for a while so it may be related to a slower-than-normal power ramp as bulk capacitors charge.  A power cycle will clear the condition every time, but any state that requires a power cycle and does not clear with a hard reset concerns me.
Has anyone else encountered this with the STM32G0 series? If so, any suggestions for resolution? Thanks!

How is the MCU supplied ? Did you scope its voltage ramp up ? Any timing data inside the datasheet related to the MCU power supply requirements ?

The MCU is supplied through a 3v3 LDO; that can be powered by several sources including USB, battery, and external PS/solar.  I've been testing with USB power.
However, I think I found the answer...see next comment.

I only noticed this happening once I set the RDP option byte to BB (level 1) and I can't replicate it with RDP set to 0xAA
I think I got nailed by errata 2.2.3 (Under Level 1 read protection, booting from Main Flash memory selected through PA14-BOOT0 pin is not functional).
Workaround: None  :-(

It turns out I was having two problems:

Errata 2.2.3 - the problem started when I enabled RDP level 1.  ST has a published errata about this: when using RDP level 1, you cannot have the BOOT0 pin enabled (must disable via nBOOT_SEL bit in option bytes). If you have it enabled, you get this intermittent lockup on power up.  It's a serious issue, but the workaround they note in the errata seems to work (set nBOOT_SEL option bit which disables selecting the boot mode via the BOOT0 pin).

I had a bad component where changes to the nBOOT_SEL option bit were not working. I replaced the uC and all seems to be working now.



Yes, check the VCC rails make sure the rails aren't dipping. On power up make sure the are monotonically increasing (continually going up with no zig-zags).
The reset system should look like this:

https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm32g030f6.pdf
Make sure the reset capacitor has a good ground.

Thanks, and sorry, 10nF was a typo (fixed), it was supposed to read 100nF.  It's a 2L board so the cap connects to top-layer ground pour through relatively wide thermal relief.
I note: errata 2.2.1 applies to my use case (LSI clocks RTC) and I wasn't resetting the backup power domain on POR; I've added that to the boot code, but still no luck.
Anything that keeps the uC from starting up on a hard reset seems like a critical issue.

Did you check the VCC rails, it would be good to post a screenshot.
